# Why use random strings for filenames instead of logical names?

Tags: file, url, filenames

I see in websites such as Facebook or Twitter, images such as profile pictures have filenames and locations such as `640122062739084800/BXK8aBbv.jpg`.

This is quite clearly generated. But why do websites to this? Why not instead have `(user_id)/image.jpg` instead which is much more logical?

Is there a security risk or is there another reason? Thanks.

Comment: Consider that `user_id` may contain a forward slash. Or in fact any other character that is invalid in pathnames for the host system or, since you may be looking at it on another OS, any other OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a script behind every 'token' you see in URL.
Tokens are a way to control what's happening and when with security.
Some characters sequence are specification of the request, even you don't understand it at fist time.

In short. Yes, its generally for security purposes, but for controls and request specifications too.

Hope it was usesfull

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So if I was to create a similar tool where a user would upload an image, a randomly generated token should be used as the filename and then stored in a database?

Comment: Yes, but only if you think that is really needed this kind of resource.

Comment: Please, if you think my answer was helpful vote for my reputation grow.